# Vim + Snippets isn't working

Tags: vim, code-snippets

I'm not sure if this question should be done in the superusers, but anyway, lets give it a try.

Here is my problem.. I'm running ubuntu 9.10 and I'm tying to create a development environment with Vim and it's plugins.
I've done everything that I needed, but I'm having some issues with the snippets:

When I'm in a model and I press:

```
bt<TAB>
```

I got:

```
belongs_to :<+association_name+><+, :class_name => "<+Object+>", :foreign_key => "<+<+object+>_id+>"+>
```

But if I start typing, instead of replace the association_name with what I type, it just place the text after the line.

Anyone know what could be happening?

Thanks.

Comment: You should mention which snippet plugin you're using, what (if any) customization of it you've done, etc.

Comment: <+ +> looks like latex-suite substitution fields...try Ctrl-j to move between them.

Answer (score 1):

not sure which plugin you're using but snipMate has a much easier config/syntax for creating and using snippets within vim,

http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2540